# Can I use toBinaryString function on matrix

Tags: java, matrix

This is the code I have written to convert chars to its equivalent integers. The values are in a 2D matrix.I want to convert these ASCII values to binary equivalent.

```
for(int a=0; a<3; a++) {
    for(int b=0; b<3; b++) {
       char character=first[a][b];
       B=(int) character;
       System.out.print(B+" ");
    }
   System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("\n");
```

I get the required output for ASCII equivalent values from the above code.
I tried using the function toBinaryString() but it converts only a single value.Can this function be used on a 2D matrix?
How can I assign these values to a 2D matrix because when I print B I only get the last element of the matrix instead of getting the complete 2D matrix?

Comment: But you already have a loop, so just replace B+" " with Integer.toBinaryString(B)+" "

Comment: Thanx....I created another for loop and displayed the binary values separately.But now when I display B I get only the last element of the ASCII equivalent matrix,can you help me how can I assign these values to a 2D matrix?

Comment: Do you talking about the same code above? If no, you can edit your question and add your new code.

Comment: Yes.I am talking about the same code above

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard method like:

```
first.toBinaryString();
```

or

```
String s = Arrays.toBinaryString(first);
```

but you can implement your own method, something like:

```
public static String charMatrixToBinaryString(char[][] matrix) {...}
```

UPD: there is your code for BinaryString output:

```
    String[][] ascii2dMatrix = new String[3][3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            ascii2dMatrix[i][j] = Integer.toBinaryString(first[i][j]);
            System.out.print(ascii2dMatrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
```